# How to style bootstrap select field with rounded corner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to style bootstrap select field with rounded corner but not work form me.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
<select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleSelect2">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Balvant25/bp8mvo7f/

Answer (score 0):

try setting the style on the css as follows:

```
.form-control{
border-radius:10px;
}
```

You can also add inline styling:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
<select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleSelect2" style="border-radius:10px">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is not i want. you can check my fiddle which i attached in question

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap already has a property of `border-radius: .25rem;` applied to its form-control class. So you need to prioritize your border-radius with `!important` like in the snippet below.

```css
.form-control {
  border-radius: 40px !important;
}
.form-control[multiple] {
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-10 col-offset-1">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not i want. you can check my fiddle which i attached in question

Comment: Your fiddle is showing a single select field but your question is a multi-select. I have added the single select into the fiddle if that is what you need.